# problem opening word documents in document library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, document-library

i encounter problem when opening word documents in document library what should i do?
[image][image]

Comment: Are you trying to open the document within Office Web Apps or the Client Application? If client application, what version of Office are you running on your workstation?

Comment: no  i want to open them in word (client application)

Comment: What version of Microsoft Office are you running on your workstation? Based on the error message, this could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality will not work in Chrome. You'll need to use IE or FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `?web=1` behind the document path (`... .doc?Web=1`).

Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: i want to open them in client application not office web